# Confidence interval of precision / recall and F1 score

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, precision-recall, confusion-matrix

To summarise the predictive power of a classifier for end users, I'm using some metrics. However, as the users input data themselves, the amount of data and class distribution varies a lot. So to inform users about the strength of the metrics, I'd like to include confidence intervals.

#### Background on the metrics

Suppose a binary classifier that is to classify 1000 items. Of those items, 700 belong to A, and 300 to B. The results are as follows:

```
         Predicted
       | # A | # B
-------+-----+-----
True A | 550 | 150
True B |  50 | 250
```

We'll call class B a positive result (1) and class A a negative one (0). So there were 550 true negatives, 150 false positives, 50 false negatives and 250 true positives.

There are some metrics [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_(information_retrieval_context)) for this classification:

$$\text{Recall} = \frac{TP}{TP+FN} = 0.833$$
$$\text{Precision} = \frac{TP}{TP + FP} = 0.625$$
$$\text{F1 score} = \frac{2}{1/recall + 1/precision} = 0.714$$

#### Suggested approach

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068858/confidence-interval-margin-of-recall-or-precision) addresses confidences of recall or precision. It suggests using an adjusted version of recall: $\text{recall} = (TP+2) / (TP+FN+4)$ and the [Wilson Score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval). The final formula would be

$$p \pm Z_\alpha \cdot \text{std_error}$$

where

$$\text{std_error} = \sqrt{\frac{recall\cdot(1-recall)}{N+4}}$$

There's something I don't understand about this approach. The formula resembles the confidence interval for a binomial distribution, but it's not quite the same. Neither is it the Wilson formulation. **Where does that additional $+4$ come from?** Maybe it is from the recall formula.

He mentions that $p$ is calculated *using* the adjusted recall. That would imply $recall = \hat{p}$, which is reinforced by the error formula. So let's use the Wilson formulation for $p$. With $n=TP+FN=300$ the final calculation with a confidence of $\alpha=0.05$ yields $z=1.96$ and:

$$p \pm Z_\alpha\cdot\text{std_err} = \frac{\hat{p} + z^2/(2n)}{1+z^2/n} \pm z\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}\cdot(1-\hat{p})}{n+4}} = 0.825 \pm 0.042$$

#### Pondering

While this does seem like a sensible result, I still wonder about the formula and the differences between the formulae presented. **What could be the basis for the $\text{std_err}$ formula?** Is it better to use the Wilson formula instead?

A similar formulation could be used for calculating the confidence interval for precision using false positives instead of false negatives. **How would this idea carry to the F1 score, which is a combination of the two, if at all?**

My statistic skills and intuition isn't so strong yet, so any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

---

#### Edit

Different approaches have little effect at least in this case

$$\text{Normal approach: } \hat{p} \pm Z_\alpha\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}\cdot(1-\hat{p})}{n}} = 0.829 \pm 0.043$$
$$\text{Wilson approach: } \frac{\hat{p} + z^2/(2n)}{1+z^2/n} \pm Z_\alpha\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}\cdot(1-\hat{p})}{n} + \frac{z^2}{4n^2}} = 0.825 \pm 0.043$$
$$\text{Above approach: } \frac{\hat{p} + z^2/(2n)}{1+z^2/n} \pm Z_\alpha\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}\cdot(1-\hat{p})}{n+4}} = 0.825 \pm 0.042$$

For smaller samples they start to vary a bit more, especially with the interval. The Wilson approach seems to give the largest intervals.

Comment: I couldn't find an answer to this myself, so I did it by propagating the uncertainties of the precision and the recall directly by hand. My code & explanation are [here](https://github.com/sousanunes/confidence_intervals).

Answer (score 4):

To give some quick answers to the points raised:

The additional "$+4$"observed when calculated the "adjusted version of recall". This comes from the viewing the occurrence of a True Positive as a success and the occurrence of a False Negative as a failure. Using this rationale, we follow the general recommendation from  Agresti & Coull (1998) "[Approximate is Better than 'Exact' for Interval Estimation of Binomial Proportions](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/agresti_coull_1998.pdf)" where we "*add two successes and two failures*" to get adjusted Wald interval. As $2 + 2 = 4$, our total sample size increases from $N$ to $N+4$. As the authors also explain it is "*identical to Bayes estimate (mean of posterior distribution) with parameters 2 and 2*". (I will revisit this point in a end).

The basis for the standard error formula shown. This is the also motivated by the "*add two successes and two failures*" rationale. This drives the $+4$ on the denominator. Regarding the numerator, please note that the estimate $\hat{p}$ should be adjusted too as mentioned above. A bit more background: assuming a 0.95 CI with $z^2 = 1.96^2 \approx 4$, then the midpoint of this adjust interval $\frac{(X+\frac{z^2}{2})}{(n +z^2)} \approx \frac{X+2}{n+4}$. Interestingly is also nearly identical to the midpoint of the 0.95 [Wilson score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval).

How this carries forward to the calculations of $F_1$. This correction in itself ($+2$ and $+4$) is somewhat trivial to be also to the calculation of the $F_1$ score;we can apply it on how we calculate Precision (or Recall) and use the result. That said, calculating the standard error of the $F_1$ is more involved. While working with the linear combination of independent random variables (RVs) is quite straightforward, $F_1$ is not a linear combination of Precision and Recall. Luckily we can express it as their harmonic mean though (i.e. $F_1 = \frac{2 * Prec * Rec}{Prec + Rec}$. It is preferable to use the harmonic mean of Precision and Recall as the way of expressing $F_1$ because it allows us to work with a [product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) when it comes to the numerator of the $F_1$ score and a [ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution) when it comes to the overall calculation. (Convenient fact: The mean calculations are straightforward as the expectation of the product of two  RVs is the product of their expectations.)

As mentioned A&C (1998) also suggests that this correction is "*identical to Bayes estimate (mean of posterior distribution) with parameters 2 and 2*". This idea is fully explored in  Goutte & Gaussier (2005) [A Probabilistic Interpretation of Precision, Recall and F-Score, with Implication for Evaluation](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-31865-1_25). Effectively we can view the whole confusion matrix as the sample realisation from a multinomial distribution. We can bootstrap it, as well as assume priors on it. To simplify things a bit a will just focus on Recall which can be assumed to be just the realisation of a Binomial distribution so we can use a Beta distribution as the prior. If we wanted to use the whole matrix we would use a [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) (i.e. a multivariate beta distribution). 
For the bootstrap also keep in mind that as Hastie et al. commented in "[Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/)" (Sect. 8.4) directly: "*we might think of the bootstrap distribution as a "poor man's" Bayes posterior. By perturbing the data, the bootstrap approximates the Bayesian effect of perturbing the parameters, and is typically much simpler to carry out.*"

OK, some code to make these concrete.

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123) 
# Define our observed sample
mySample =c( rep("TP", 250), rep("TN",550), rep("FN", 50), rep("FP", 150))
# Define our "Recall" sampling function
getRec = function(){xx = sample(mySample, replace=TRUE); 
                    sum(xx=="TP")/(sum("TP"==xx) + sum("FN" == xx))}
# Create our bootstrap Recall sample (Give it ~ 50")
myRecalls = replicate(n = 1000000, getRec())
mean(myRecalls) # 0.8333322

# Get our empirical density and calculate the mean
theKDE = density(myRecalls)
plot(theKDE, lty=2, main= "Distribution of Recall")
grid()
abline(v = mean(myRecalls), lty=2)

theSupport = seq(min(theKDE$x), max(theKDE$x), by = 0.0001)

# Explore different priors
# Haldane prior (Complete uncertainty)
lines(col='green', theSupport, dbeta(theSupport, shape1=250+0, shape2=50+0))
maxHP = theSupport[which.max(dbeta(theSupport, shape1=250+0, shape2=50+0))]
abline(v = maxHP, col='green')

# Flat prior
lines(col='cyan', theSupport, dbeta(theSupport, shape1=250+1, shape2=50+1))
maxFP = theSupport[which.max(dbeta(theSupport, shape1=250+1, shape2=50+1))]
abline(v = maxFP, col='cyan')

# A&C suggestion
lines(col='red', theSupport, dbeta(theSupport, shape1=250+2, shape2=50+2))
maxAC = theSupport[which.max(dbeta(theSupport, shape1=250+2, shape2=50+2))]
abline(v = maxAC, col='red')

legend( "topright", lty=c(2,1,1,1),
        legend = c(paste0("Boostrap Mean: (", signif(mean(myRecalls),4), ")"), 
                   paste0("HP Posterior MAP: (", signif(maxHP,4), ")"), 
                   paste0("FP Posterior MAP: (", signif(maxFP,4), ")"), 
                   paste0("A&C Posterior MAP: (", signif(maxAC,4), ")")),
        col=c("black","green","cyan", "red"))
```

[image]

As it can be seen our flat prior's (Beta distribution $B(1,1)$) posterior [MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) and our bootstrap estimates effectively coincide. Similarly, our A&C posterior MAP shows the strongest shrinkage towards a mean of 0.50 while the [Haldane prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Haldane.27s_prior_probability_.28Beta.280.2C0.29.29)'s (Beta distribution $B(0,0)$) posterior MAP is the most optimistic for our Recall. Notice that if we accept a particular posterior, the actual 0.95 CI calculation becomes trivial as we can directly get it from the quantile functions. For example, assuming a flat prior `qbeta(1-0.025, 251,51)` will give us the upper 0.95 CI for the posterior as `0.8711659`. Similarly the posterior mean is estimated as $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}$ or in the case of a flat prior as `0.8311` (`251/(251+51)`).