# Confidence intervals for Object Detection metrics

Tags: confidence-interval, precision-recall, object-detection, precision

I would like to come back on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/530121/320933) "When do we require to calculate the confidence Interval?" since recently a reviewer asked me to provide confidence intervals for metrics regarding my work about object detection (precision, recall, F-score). I have never had this kind of request before and never seen anything like that on papers I had the chance to read or review. My idea it to follow this [approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/363382/320933) but was wondering if it's really necessary given a test set sufficiently large (how large to be considered "safe"?).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.